# Why `Character.getNumericValue` for 'a' returns 10 instead of its Unicode Index 97?

Tags: java, unicode

I am learning Java and currently I am stuck with Characters.

I know that I can initialize a char using one of these corresponding values:

```
char ch1 = 'a';
char ch2 = 97;
char ch3 = '\u0061';
```

Please explain me why, when I am using this method, I get a 10, not 97?

```
int numValue = Character.getNumericValue(ch1); // returns 10
```

Thank you in advance for your time!
Daniel

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-int-). a is 10 in hexadecimal, or in any other base above 10. Whereas if you did `int numValue = ch1;` *then* you would get 97.

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char))

Comment: You are probably misunderstanding purpose of `Character.getNumericValue` method. It is not to return *Unicode index* of character, but *value* it represents. For instance character `'1'` represents numerical value `1`, or Romain character `Ⅼ` represents `50`. To print Unicode index of character you can for instance *cast* it to `int` like `System.out.println((int) ch1);`.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation of [`public static int getNumericValue(int codePoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-int-)

> The letters A-Z in their uppercase ('\u0041' through '\u005A'), lowercase ('\u0061' through '\u007A'), and full width variant ('\uFF21' through '\uFF3A' and '\uFF41' through '\uFF5A') forms have numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode specification, which does not assign numeric values to these char values.

Comment: Hello. If you are quoting please also include the source.

Comment: I'm sorry because I'm new here, I thought it was included by default when I do paste.. Thank you for remembering me that.